# Suggested edits count includes a user's own tag wiki edits

Tags: bug, editing, suggested-edits, review, tag-wiki

In [review](https://askubuntu.com/review/), I'm told there are 3 suggested edits for me to approve/reject/improve:

[image: suggested edits shown when on another tab]

<sup>**(These images are from the old review system; the new system's interface is different but this still seems to occur.)**</sup>

It looks like that when I am on any tab except the suggested edits tab itself. But when I switch to the suggested edits tab, so that I can review edits, there's nothing there:

[image: no suggested edits shown on the suggested edits tab]

I switch back to any other tab, and I see that there are 3 suggested edits again. I switch back to the 3 suggested edits tab, and they edits are gone. So this is not caused just by the edits having been reviewed by someone else.

This does not appear browser-specific.

**Update:** [jokerdino](https://askubuntu.com/users/25798/jokerdino) has pointed out that these 3 suggested edits that I cannot review were [my own tag wiki edit suggestions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5222600#5222600). That clarifies for me **why** this is occurring, but it still seems like a bug. Shouldn't the number of suggested edits listed in review for any user be the number of pending suggestions *that user* can review?

Please note that this will only happen for users with at least [5,000 reputation](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) and less than [20,000](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/trusted-user). This is the rep range in which a user can review a tag wiki edit but cannot make one without it being approved.

**Related:** https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117671/when-you-suggest-an-edit-to-a-tag-wiki-the-suggested-edits-counter-is-increased