# Strange: I have some pending edit review, but the review page says 0 suggested edits pending

Tags: support, review-queue

I recently submitted 4 (no, actually 3) edit suggestions on Ask Ubuntu, but I spotted out a strange behaviour:

A lot of my edits, when I submitted to Ask Ubuntu, at first showed up in the counter in the suggested edits in https://askubuntu.com/review, but after the first reviewer approved my suggested edit, the counter goes back to 0 for 5 to 30 minutes before the counter goes back to 1.

I thought this was normal behavior in Ask Ubuntu at first as I encountered this every time before I post this, but today it gets my nerves up too much that I posted this issue here.

I just submitted 6 (I think) suggested edits to Ask Ubuntu, where 3 of them are approved by users who posted their questions. After a while (around 30 to 40 minutes later), I just got interested in seeing the number of pending suggested edits, and I got alarmed: ***0*** appeared in the page.

[image: Suggested Edit Behaviour]

I have never seen this issue before. Yes, one of my pending edit got approved my a reviewer, I understand that it might not show up in the counter of suggested edits, but how about the other 2? I see no reviewer approving or rejecting my suggested edits, and the counter of pending suggested edits still shows ***0***.

I want to know what happened, as it affects the edit suggestions efficiency a **lot**, and I do not hope this issue will affect other users submitting and reviewing the suugested edits.

**Edit:** I just checked again, my proposed edits are proposed more than 27 minutes already, no reviewers handle my edit suggestions, and the counter for pending suggested edits ***still*** shows ***0***.

**Edit 2：** Updates again. The counter for pending suggested edits ***still*** shows ***0***, but 2 of my suggested edits have activities now. However, 1 of them still do not have any activities. I suppose some reviewer opened my suggested edit and go AFK.

**Edit 3:** Incognito mode screenshot here. I got another pending edit, where I did not login, but the counter shows 1.

[image: Incognito mode]

The point is, Last time when I got to the review page, both of logged in one and incognito one shows a counter of 0. I believe that the counter will show the same for everyone.

Comment: As the other answer says, items you cannot review are not shown to you and since you can't review your own edits, the counter doesn't reflect them. I could see all three just fine and have dealt with them.

Comment: @terdon [Although...](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3599/suggested-edits-count-includes-a-users-own-tag-wiki-edits) I don't really understand [the explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109634/185080).

Comment: But in the past I can actually see the counter goes 1 or more - that is the point I want to say. I have even seen it goes up to 3. Then why would this actually happen?

Answer (score 6):

Open the reviews page in Incognito Mode, so you're logged out, and you'll see it. The review count won't reflect anything you submitted.